# Is it safe to return "this" from a Spring bean method?

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-bean

I want to create a chain api on a prototype bean.

```java
@Component
@Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ReportGenerator {
    List lines = new ArrayList();
    public ReportGenerator append(String line){
        lines.add(line);
        return this;
    }
    
}



public class SomeSingletonBean{

    @Autowire 
    ReportGenerator rg;

    void doSomeWork(){
      rg.append("a").append("b");
    }
}
```

The above seems to work fine.

But is this safe in all cases?

Also, can I safely do the same in a bean scoped "session"?

Comment: At core Spring is Java. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/can-we-return-this-keyword-from-a-method-in-java

Comment: @Ajay Kumar "At core Spring is Java". Exactly! And in java the current object ( `this` ) is not always the object on which the current method was originally called.